# Liferay - Error setting preferences of sitemap portlet in Theme

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-theme

I am adding a sitemap portlet at the footer of my theme, and when I instance it I set the preferences for the root layout id, display depth and show hidden pages.
My portal-normal.vm snippet:

```
#* Sitemap for the Footer Links *#
    #set ($portlet_id = '85')
    #set ($instance_id = 'AAAC')
#* Preferences *#
    #set ($rootLayoutId = "f74bd692-715f-4532-8490-dee211bebed8")
    #set ($displayDepth = 0)
    #set ($showHiddenPages = true)
    #set ($myPortletId = "${portlet_id}_INSTANCE_${instance_id}")
    $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('portlet-setup-show-borders', 'false')
    $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('rootLayoutId', 'f74bd692-715f-4532-8490-dee211bebed8')
    $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('displayDepth', '0')
    $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('showHiddenPages', 'false')
$theme.runtime($myPortletId, '', $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.reset())
```

But the portlet is displayed with the basic preferences.
Haven't found info about preferences names/values, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

**EDIT with the solution**
Following @Pankaj Kathiriya indication i wrote next code that is correctly working:

```
#* Sitemap for the Footer Links *#
    #set ($portlet_id = '85')
    #set ($instance_id = 'AABB')
#* Instanciate the portlet *#
    #set ($myPortletId = "${portlet_id}_INSTANCE_${instance_id}")
    $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('portlet-setup-show-borders', 'false')
    $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('rootLayoutUuid', 'f74bd692-715f-4532-8490-dee211bebed8')
    $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('displayDepth', '0')
    $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('showHiddenPages', 'true')
    $theme.runtime($myPortletId, '', $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
#* Reset preferences *#
    $velocityPortletPreferences.reset()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is at line below:

```
 $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('rootLayoutId', 'f74bd692-715f-4532-8490-dee211bebed8')
```

It should be

```
$velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('rootLayoutUuid', 'f74bd692-715f-4532-8490-dee211bebed8')
```

It should be **rootLayoutUuid**

Regards

Comment: I will give this a try, but non of the preferences is working either, so it doesn't completely explains it.
Thanks!

Comment: I did not get "so it doesn't completely explains it."

Comment: This worked! Besides, the value for the showHiddenPages was wrong; completely my fault. I will accept the answer and update the code with the whole snippet.
Thanks again! :-)